# storing the contents in a array and displaying

Tags: c

I have written code to generate a prime number within a range. And then trying to store the generated prime number in an array:

```
 if(prime)
   printf("\n%d", n);
 prime_array[k]=n;
 k++;
```

Then trying to print the contents of array:

```
for(z=0;z<6;z++)
  printf("%d\n",prime_array[z]);
```

The output that I get is incorrect. What is wrong?

Comment: what do you see? what do you expect to see?

Comment: your `if` affects `printf` only. I'm not sure, but probably you should put `printf; prime_array[k]=n; k++` in one block between `{}`.

Comment: @khachik maybe you should post this as an answer. based on the little information we got from the OP, yours seems to be most likely solution.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming everything else is correct, you should consider the following: `printf` goes inside `if` block, but everything else doesn't. It probably should be:

```
if(prime) {
  printf("\n%d", n);
  prime_array[k]=n;
  k++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the code you've posted, you are trying to cast an integer (n) in something that seems to be a char (prime_array[k]), it can't work because 'n' and 'prime_array[k]' dont have the same type and also because you can't cast an integer in an array like that.

If you want to put an integer in an array, you can use the function sprintf from stdio.h.
Man of this function : http://man.cx/sprintf%283%29

Anhuin.

Comment: what!? sorry, but that's not right at all! first of all, there's no reason to think `prime_array[k]` is a `char` or that `n` is an integer. second, even if it were, you can definitely cast an `int` to a `char` if the integer is within the range representable by a `char` (-128 to 127). third, you can definitely put an integer in an integer array (or a char array) by simple assignment. `sprintf` could be used if you wanted a string representation of the number.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I didn't understood properly the question. I though he wanted to cast an integer in a char array.
And yes, i agree with you, you can cast an integer in a char but you'll just keep the first byte (or the last depending of the endian mode).